# Is Casting and Calling a Function's Parameter Count Specified Behaviour?

Tags: c++

The question regards - specifically - the reinterpret_cast and the subsequent function call using a nullptr as the third argument. Is this specified behaviour?

I use malloc/free because deleting void pointers using `delete` is unspecified behaviour. Regardless; the question should consider non-void pointers as well (as arguments).

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

void *add2Ints(void *a, void *b)
{
    void *res = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *((int *) res) = *((int *) a) + *((int *) b);
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    void *y = malloc(sizeof(int));

    *((int *) x) = 31;
    *((int *) y) = 16;

    void *(*add2Ints_p)(void*, void*, void*) = reinterpret_cast<void *(*)(void*, void*, void*)>(add2Ints);

    void *z = add2Ints_p(x,y,nullptr);
    std::cout << *((int *) z);
    free(x);
    free(y);
    free(z);
}
```

Comment: I feel like I'll have a nightmare full of pointer casting tonight...

Comment: Yes, because you can only cast to a type and then cast back to the original type with `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @Seth I read from the standard that `reinterpret_cast` only guarantees that one can cast from X to Y, and then back to X, and the behaviour will be specified as if the pointer was X. Nothing more.

However, here I cast to a `type` with a different number of arguments. Afaik arguments are on the stack so the third nullptr should be ignored, but I am afraid that the `void *res` may simply overwrite that nullptr... I'll do some tests.

Comment: @BourgondAries that's exactly what I said, and if you read that, then why are you asking this question? Also for a more complete specification read the Type Aliasing part of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast (strict aliasing rule)

Comment: @BourgondAries tests don't help in understanding UB. And the type of the functions are different, so accessing it through another typed pointer is UB.

Comment: @Seth so if I call add2Ints_p(x,y,nullptr), yet add2Ints takes 2 arguments, is it undefined behaviour or not?

Comment: @BourgondAries like I just said, it is, because you are violating strict aliasing rules. Read the link I provided.

Comment: @Seth you are indeed correct. I seemed to not have thought clearly enough about the laws of `reinterpret_cast`. Alas, I will probably have to pass multivariadic arguments though a single pointer, with a length specifier or a nullptr terminator array.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour. The caller will produce the correct code for calling a function with three parameters. The function only has two. This can go wrong in any weird way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only legal thing to do with a pointer casted with `reinterpret_cast` is to cast it back to its original type.

So, here we are definitely in UB-land (and if the calling convention mandates callee cleanup you will definitely smash the stack or crash on return).

Comment: I see that now. Thanks. Is there any way to make this defined behaviour? Considering that static_cast does not seem to allow it.

Comment: @BourgondAries: The only well-defined way to call a function with the wrong number of parameters is to have a forwarding function in between.  This is usually called "binding".  Have a look at `std::bind`.  And then you'll need to use something stateful, like `std::function`, instead of plain function pointers.

Comment: Is the target function signature fixed? Can't you just write a forwarder function with the correct signature that will just call the original, omitting the third parameter?

Comment: I am aware of bind; but I am working with a low-level interface (dynamic loading of functions from shared objects), so I need a multivariadic interface. I'm probably going to use:
(void **ar, std::size_t size), where ar is an array to all the arguments and size the number of elements in that array.

Comment: @BourgondAries: If you want to see a system that does exactly that, look at COM's `IDispatch::Invoke()`.

Comment: @Matteo; no the target function is non-fixed, the problem I am facing is that if I impose the array-of-pointer passing, then I need to convert or create a wrapper for each function. This seems tedious. The UB in my question functions on my machine, and this would be desired behaviour.

Comment: @Ben Volgt; Alright; I shall take a look. It seems microsoft specific, is that correct?

Comment: @BourgondAries: Variadic templates should largely automate the wrapping.

Comment: @BourgondAries: Yes, COM is an MS Windows technology.  Not telling you to use it, but there's a lot to be learned from existing designs that have stood the test of time.

Comment: @Ben: I think it is impossible for me to utilize variadic templates as the functions are imported into the working space during run-time. I will look into COM and perhaps something multi-platform can be spawned from that system.

Comment: @BourgondAries: Multiplatform derivative of COM: [Mozilla XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/XPCOM)  But I don't know if `IDispatch` is used in it, or just as an interface layer making it work with "real" (Microsoft) COM.